# Check for block type in THEME_preprocess_menu_local_task

Tags: theming, 9

I want to make changes to local task tabs of a certain custom block type (`mini_layout`).

I can do this for certain node types in my theme with `THEME_preprocess_menu_local_task()`, and there I can use the following to check the node and node type first.

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node && $node->getType() == 'content_type') {
  // my code
}
```

But how do I check for something like `$block` and `$block->getType() == 'mini_layout'`? (Which is definitely not right.)

Should I do this in the module, or is it better to stay in the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather use **[hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/9.3.x)** just because they made a dedicated hook for it. So might as well use it.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  $is_a_block = !empty(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters()->get('block_content'));
  if ($is_a_block) {
    $is_a_mini_layout_block = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters()->get('block_content')->bundle() == 'mini_layout';
    if ($is_a_mini_layout_block) {
      // my code
    }
  }
}
```

> Should I do this in the module, or is it better to stay in the theme?

Better to use a module since these pages use the Admin theme and you should never touch the core admin theme. So unless you're using a custom admin theme, then, and only then, you can consider using theme.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Thanks for the extra context.